# let $p$ and $q$ be relatively prime then find how many positive integers less than $pq$ exists which are relatively prime to $pq$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let $p$ and $q$ be relatively prime then find how many positive integers less than $pq$ exists which are relatively prime to $pq$

I'm not good at such questions. Answer seems to be $(p-1)(q-1)$ but couldn't get why. Any help?

Comment: The answer is $(p-1)(q-1)$ if $p$ and $q$ are different prime numbers.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

By *Gauß' lemmma*, an integer is coprime with $pq$ if and only if it is coprime with each.